# How to verify SWT application numeric-field-widget error from its object properties

Tags: automation, swt, error-messaging

I have SWT application, in which application has numeric-field-widget to enter a number. When an invalid number is entered in numeric-field-widget, the text box border changes to red color and error icon is displayed at right side of text box.

I just want to verify error message and along with error icon in automation.

Can you please suggest a way to verify?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "in automation"? Are you doing unit tests? Or are you using some testing framework on an entire application?

Comment: I need to develop a automation test case to verify error message